# give a user X number of chances to input a value in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, loops

Hi I am a newbie learning PHP ( & on stackoverflow too)- I am trying to solve a simple problem but unable to do. I hae already searched on google and stackoverflow before posting a question as I didnt want to waste other time but for a week now am unable to solve this issue.

I am writing a simple program in php that lets user input a number and checks if the value entered is 5. If true it echo's "you win" else "try again". I am able to do this

The tricky part for me is I want to give him only 10 chances and try as I might using basic PHP am unable to do this. Have tried using if, for, do while but am unable to "loop the html"..I dont know jquery etc and am trying to accomplish this with PHP only. I havent yet progessed to learning sessions etc. Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<body>
TRY AND GUESS THE NUMBER
<br/>
<br/>
<form method="POST" action="gullible.php">
Please enter any number :<input type="text" name="num">
<input type="hidden" name="cnt" value=<?php $cnt=0 ?>>
<input type="submit" name="go">
</body>
</html>
<?php
$i=0;
 if ($_POST['num']!=5)
 {
 $i++;
 echo $i;
 echo " Please try again";
 }
 else 
 echo "You win the game";
 ?>'
```

Comment: On topic: You need [random numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) and [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the variable in some manner such that it persists. in your script, you are setting `$i` to `0` each time it runs.  Plus you are setting the value incorrectly in your hidden input.

One way of doing this is using a Session variable, such as `$_SESSION['cnt']`

My PHP is a bit rusty, but here's an example using Session variables:

```
$max_guesses = 10;

if( !isset($_SESSION['cnt']) ){
  $_SESSION['cnt'] = 0;
}

if( $_SESSION['cnt']++ > $_max_guesses ){
  echo "Maximum tries exceeded";
} else {
  echo "Try again";
}
```

If you don't want to, or can't use a session variable, you could use the hidden input field, like you tried to:

```
<?php
    if( !isset($_POST['cnt']) ){
      $cnt = 0;
    } else {
      $cnt = $_POST['cnt'];
    }

    if( $cnt++ > $_max_guesses ){
      echo "Maximum tries exceeded";
    } else {
      echo "Try again";
    }
?>

<input type='hidden' name='cnt' value='<?php echo $cnt ?>' />
```

(Note if your form uses GET instead, just replace `$_POST` with `$_GET` or you can use `$_REQUEST` if you're not sure, but probably better not to.

Comment: Hi tom - thanks for the help - will try this and revert - thanks for again for taking time to answer my question

Comment: @BhaveshShah No problem.  You might need to add `session_start()` at the top of the code... I don't remember for sure.

Answer (score 0):

After successful login of the user set the chances variable to 10 like this.

```
$_SESSION['nofchances']=10;
```

After setting this flag on the successful authentication page. Redirect to your PLAIN html code.

**EDITED :**

**question.html**

```
<html>
<body>
TRY AND GUESS THE NUMBER
<br/>
<br/>
<form method="POST" action="gullible.php">
Please enter any number :<input type="text" name="num">
<input type="submit" name="go">
</body>
</html>
```

**gullible.php**

```
<?php
 if($_SESSION['nofchances']!=0)
 {
 if ($_POST['num']!=5)
 {
 $_SESSION['nofchances'] = $_SESSION['nofchances'] - 1;
 echo "You have ".$_SESSION['nofchances']." no of chances to try";
 echo "<br>Please try again";
 header("location:question.html");
 }
 else
 {
 echo "You won the game";
 $_SESSION['nofchances']=10; // resetting back
 }
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Your chances expired";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Hi Shankar Thanks for taking time out to answer my question. I tried this code but the counter value does not get subtracted. The form is in html - the code is in php. I think everytime we hit submit the code refreshes & thats why the $_Session gets reset to 9 ( it runs one )

Comment: Hi tried again got an error - where should the $_SESSION['nofchances']=10; line be ? in gullible.php ? I dont any login pages as this is just a simple script to improve my coding

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use sessions yet you could define a hidden input field which stores the current try then incriment "+1" it whenever the submit is pressed / the site is reloaded. Something like:

```
if( isset($_POST['try']) ) {
   $try = $_POST['try'];
   $try += 1;
} else {
   $try = 0;
}
```

add the hidden field in your form like:

```
$hiddenTry = '<input type="hidden" value="'. $try .'" name="try"/>';
```

and add a if clause to when to show the form like:

```
if ( $try <= 10 ) {
  //your form
}
```

Comment: hi Thanks - will try and see if this works - BTW - whats the meaning of --> value=". $try ." can we directly assign a variable like this or should this be within the <?php ?> tag ? ... what are the "." for ?

Comment: Oh sry in my example the input is a string and the '. $try .' pretty much stops the string appends the value of $try and opens it again. I will change that after commenting. You could indded just write <?php $try ?>.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function in onBlur/onChange

```
<script>
function test()
{
var count=<?php echo $count;?>;
var guess=parseInt($('#hid_num').val())+1;
if(guess>count)
{
 alert('Your chances over!');
}
else
{
$('#hid_num').val(guess);
}
}
</script>

<input type="text" onblur="test();" id="chk_estimate" />
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="hid_num" /></body>
```

Comment: And the user can simply edit the page at runtime and change the amount of tries they have. It might be good in addition to using server side code but not good on its own.

Comment: hi pardon my ignorance but is this in PHP ? - as I learning PHP and know only that - thanks for helping

Comment: k thanks - will be learning jquery in a couple of months right now its php+mysql ..

Answer (score 0):

i made this for you i hope it can help you learn something new (i edited it a couple of times to make variable names easier to understand make sure you check it again - i added a cheat also :) )

```
<?php
    session_start(); // with this we can use the array $_SESSION to store values across page views of a user.

    mt_srand(time()); // this is to ensure mt_rand function will produce random values. just ignore it for now. it's another story :)

    $max_tries = 10; // limit of guesses

    $_SESSION['the_magic_number']=!isset($_SESSION['the_magic_number'])?mt_rand(0,100):$_SESSION['the_magic_number'];
    // the previous line is a one-liner if then else statement. one-liners works like this: 
    // $my_name_will_be=($isBoy==true)?"George":"Mary";

    if(isset($_POST['num'])) // if this pageview is from a valid POST then...
    {
        $_SESSION['current_try']=isset($_SESSION['current_try'])?$_SESSION['current_try']+1:1;
        // one-line if then else again. This increases the try user is now, or resets it to one
    }
?>  
<html>
    <body>
        TRY AND GUESS THE NUMBER
        <br/>
        <br/>
<?php   
    if ($_SESSION['current_try']<=$max_tries) // if user has more tries available
    {
         if(intval($_POST['num'])==$_SESSION['the_magic_number']) // did he found it?
         {
             echo "You found it! Gongratulations! Click <a href=''>here</a> to try again!";

             // oh and do not forget to reset the variables (you found this bug, well done!)
             $_SESSION['current_try']=1;
             $_SESSION['the_magic_number']=NULL;
         }
         else
         {
             // if he didn't found it, display the status of tries left, and the form to try again
             echo "This is your try ".($_SESSION['current_try'])." of ".$max_tries." Good Luck!";
?>
        <form method="POST" action="mygame.php">
            Please enter any number :
            <input type="text" name="num"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="tries" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['tries']))?$_POST['tries']-1:$max_tries; ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" name="go"/>
        </form>
        <span style="color:white;background-color:white;"><?php echo "You bloody cheater! The magic number is ".$_SESSION['the_magic_number'];?></span>
<?php
         }
    }
    else
    { 
        // here we are if no tries left! An empty href to reload the page, and we resetting our variables.
        // the_magic_number gets NULL so at the start of script it will be "not set" and will get a mt_rand(0,100) value again
        echo "You lost! Sorry! Click <a href=''>here</a> to try again!";
        $_SESSION['current_try']=1;
        $_SESSION['the_magic_number']=NULL;
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

the span at the end is a cheat ;) press ctrl+a to use it !!!

Comment: Hi Excellent answer Thanks a ton works like a charm and does more BTW when you get the right answer ( or use ctrl a :) ) you are directed to the page to try again and if you click "here" then your chances left continues from where you left of ? also how does ctrl+a work ? and wondering if there is any other way to do this without using sessions ? .. I tried to push the $_POST['num'] value into an array and then tried counting the number elements in the array but got an error - $c=$_POST['num'];
echo $c;
$a=array_push($c);
$s=count($a);

Comment: @BhaveshShah hehe if you want to reset the tries after winning, simply put a `$_SESSION['current_try']=1;$_SESSION['the_magic_number']=NULL;` after the winning echo (i updated it!).CRTL+A just selects all the text. Text is already there but is invisible because its white color against white background, but when you select it, it becomes white color over blue background (visible)! Yes you can do it without sessions, by passing all the variables on every form request, but then a cheater client could "change" the values before submitting and could always submit that he has 10 more tries!

Comment: :) should have understood the ctrl+a - its damn simple and in the face :) LOL ........... any idea reg the array option would that work too? ..$c=$_POST['num']; echo $c; $a=array_push($c); $s=count($a);

Comment: @BhaveshShah i moved the span cheat under the form, because now it was displayed also at the win-lose echo's where it was not needed. the code `$c=$_POST['num']; echo $c; $a=array_push($c); $s=count($a);` i think the array_push must be like this `array_push($a,$c);` so $a will be an array that gets $c as last element. but you must save the $a across pageviews. you must use `$_SESSION['a'];` instead of the variable `$a;` which is lost in each pageview! `$_SESSION['a'];` will be preserved across pageviews!

Comment: understood ... thanks a ton once again sharky for your detailed help, time & effort. deeply appreciate the same.. tried upvoting the answer but need 15 votes - so will do so once i reach there :) ...